# Ionic App crash after adding URL Scheme in Xcode for Firebase Authentication

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic4, cordova-plugin-firebasex

I have used cordova-plugin-firebasex plugin in project for Firebase Authentication login with
phoneNumber verification, After adding phone number in FirebasePlugin.verifyPhoneNumber function getting below error :

[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff8002ebb0
2020-12-22 14:41:23.809805+0530 2MIL[63531:1837469] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff8002ebb0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2041daf2 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20177e78 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2042c6f7 +[NSObject(NSObject) instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:] + 0
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20422032 ***forwarding*** + 1489
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20424068 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   2MIL                                0x000000010a2e6876 -[FIRPhoneAuthProvider internalVerifyPhoneNumber:UIDelegate:completion:] + 118
6   2MIL                                0x000000010a2e5c68 __64-[FIRPhoneAuthProvider verifyPhoneNumber:UIDelegate:completion:]_block_invoke + 280
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010bcae7ec _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010bcaf9c8 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010bcb6296 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 796
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010bcb6f67 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 439
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010bcc2de2 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 882
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5e739a3d _pthread_wqthread + 290
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5e738b77 start_wqthread + 15
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff8002ebb0'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 732.18.0.2 - Device: iPhone 12

tried lot of solution but did't help, Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try adding in ```Signing & Capabilities```  capability ```Background Modes``` and check ```Remote Notifications``` ?

Comment: @ShinichiKudo , yes i already added both Background Modes and Remote Notifications